# Getting oracle data in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i am learning hibernate. i have created a simple web application in which i am getting data from oracle 11g using hibernate.

My hibernate.cfg.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">titu</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <mapping class="Course" package="com.vaannila.course.Course.java" resource="com/vaannila/course/Course.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have a table "Courses" table in database, from i want to get data. For this  i have created a mapping XML file and POJO file.

Course.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.vaannila.course.Course" table="COURSES">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the course details.
      </meta>
      <id name="courseId" column="COURSE_ID" type="integer"/>
      <property name="courseName" column="COURSE_NAME" type="string" not-null="true"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Course.java :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.vaannila.course;

/**
 *
 * @author titu
 */
import org.hibernate.*;
public class Course {

    int courseId ;
    String courseName;

    public Course() {}

    public Course(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public int getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(int courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
}
```

I want to get data on a jsp page which is as follows :

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Dec 9, 2011, 10:07:21 PM
    Author     : titu
--%>

<%@page import="com.vaannila.course.Course"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.vaannila.common.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

        Session db_session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction= null;
        Integer courseId= null;

        try{
            if(db_session==null)
                               {
                out.println("This is null");
            }
            transaction= db_session.beginTransaction();
            List courses= db_session.createQuery("from Course").list();
            for(Iterator iterator= courses.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
                               {
                Course course= (Course) iterator.next();
                out.println(course.getCourseName());
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException  e){
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            db_session.close();
        }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have create a "HibernateUtil" class for creating session factory object :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.vaannila.common;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author titu
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static{
        try{
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
             }
        catch(Throwable ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial session factory creation failed " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
     return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

When i am running this project in tomcat server then, it is giving null pointer exception. When i debug my project then i found that

```
transaction= db_session.beginTransaction();
```

this line in jsp is giving me null. Means beginTransaction() returns null. I dont know why it is so ?

Please suggest me , Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure? Transaction was null to begin with. Did you step over?

Answer (score 0):

You need not have transaction for this. Since you just want to read from the table and not write into the table.